# General expression for the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=\Gamma(1-\beta x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am trying to find the $n$-th order derivative of the function:
$$f\left(x\right)=\Gamma\left(1-\beta x\right)$$

at $t=0$. To be more specific, the general expression for:

$$\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n}}{\mathrm{d}^{n} x}\Gamma\left(1-\beta x\right) \right|_{x=0}$$

whereby $\beta>0$. I tried using Mathematica to see if there is any pattern, but I couldn't find any. However, from Wikipedia, the general expression

$$\frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n}\,\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1} e^{-t} (\ln t)^n \, \mathrm{d}t$$

gives

$$\frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n}\,\Gamma(1-\beta x) = \int_0^\infty t^{-\beta x} e^{-t} (\ln t)^n \, \mathrm{d}t.$$

I can't simplify any further than this.

Comment: Please see whether this helps you: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/psifun_11.pdf

Comment: Thank you @Rohan. I managed to find a few more information based on the document and edited my question accordingly. Unfortunately, still no luck.

Comment: Please check if it is $\frac{e^{-t}\times (\ln t)^{n-1}}{a}$.

Comment: @Rohan is that the final answer or the integral?

Comment: I think so. I just integrated your function. I substituted $\beta$ for $a$.

Comment: @Rohen, I don't think that is correct. Kindly refer to the answer provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using induction, you can easily proof
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \Gamma(1-\beta x) = (-\beta)^n \Gamma^{(n)}(1 -\beta x)$$

It remains to calculate the high order derivatives of the gamma function at $1$. However, I am afraid there is no simple formula for this. The values can be recursively recovered using the [polygamma functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_260.htm), but these formulae will get very big very quickly and contain a lot of values of the zeta function.

Comment: Thank you @Dominik. I arrived to this final form as well. I don't think it can be simplified any further than this.

Comment: @arvindrajan92 Near the end of the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) right before you hit the fourier series expansion section, the $n$th derivative of the Gamma function is expressed in closed form in terms of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Yes, thank you @SimpleArt